# Federated Eclipse plugin update site

Tags: deployment, update, eclipse

I'd like to provide an Eclipse update site on an internal corporate server so that we can manage the deployment of Eclipse features to our developers (as long as this is allowed by the plug-ins licence of course).

Essentially I'd like one update site where we can store the plugins and developers can connect to this as needed. We can also then deploy updates to this site so that we can keep the developers machines synchronised and ensure plugins are compatible with each other and work well together.

I couldn't find any documentation on how to do this online, though I'm sure there must be some out there. Does anyone have any pointers or can provide an overview of what is required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new update site can be created in Eclipse by doing the following:

1. From an eclipse installation with the neccessary plugins create a new "Update Site Project"
2. After following the wizard open the `site.xml` file with the "Site Manifest Editor" (the default).
3. Add features from the Eclipse installation.
4. Select Build All to create the site structure.

After following these steps the structure needed will have been created. You can then deploy this static structure onto a web server for other members of the team to access.

Answer (score 1):

I posted a similar question [last September on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131704/is-it-possible-to-make-an-eclipse-p2-provisioning-mechanism-running-locally).

The p2 mechanism was clearly too young with eclipse3.4.

Since then, I only found (with eclipse 3.5 Galileo):

[Composing and updating custom Eclipse distros](http://aniefer.blogspot.com/2009/07/composing-and-updating-custom-eclipse.html)

(not tested myself, but it is supposed to be a way to define your own Eclipse distro, and their updates)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to visit an existing update site and get the general structure. As far as I know you dont need any special configuration for that. The archieves are auto detected by Eclipse Update Manager...